# Why is xarray introducing random numbers to a variable inside a NetCDF4 file when loading?

Tags: python, plot, loading, python-xarray, netcdf4

**Problem:**

I have created a NetCDF4 file that when opened using xarray, high values are introduced to the variable of interest and the kernel keeps crashing. I do not see the high values when loading into MATLAB suggesting that it is perhaps an incompatibility issue between the NetCDF4 file and xarray?

**This is what I do:**

I first create a NetCDF4 file including my variable of interest:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Create data
data_2_save = np.squeeze(np.float32(np.zeros([6,29947])))
data_2_save[0,1000:27300] = np.nan; 
data_2_save[1,1010:27310] = np.nan; 
data_2_save[2,1050:27350] = np.nan; 
data_2_save[3,1000:27300] = np.nan; 
data_2_save[4,900:27300] = np.nan; 
data_2_save[5,100:27300] = np.nan; 
# time range
t = np.float32(range(-2921,27026,1))
# for other dimension
d = np.arange(1,7)
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# create NetCDF4 file
filename = 'test.nc'
dataset = Dataset(filename, 'w',  format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC') 
fillvalue = 999999
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# define dimensions
TIME_DIM = dataset.createDimension('TIME', None)
D_DIM = dataset.createDimension('D', np.size(d))
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# create variables
TIME = dataset.createVariable('TIME', np.float32, ('TIME',)) 
D = dataset.createVariable('D', np.int32, ('D',))
VAR = dataset.createVariable('VARIABLE', np.float32, ('TIME','D'), 
                              fill_value=fillvalue)
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# VAR
VAR.long_name = 'name'
VAR.valid_max = np.float32(np.nanmax(data_2_save))
VAR.valid_min = np.float32(np.nanmin(data_2_save))
VAR.coordinates = 'TIME D'
VAR.comment = ('A comment goes here')
# Time
time_unit_out= "days since 1950-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"
TIME.units = time_unit_out
TIME.long_name = 'analysis time'
TIME.standard_name = 'time'
TIME.valid_max = np.nanmax(t)
TIME.valid_min = np.nanmin(t)
TIME.axis = 'T'
TIME.calendar = 'gregorian'
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# D
D.standard_name = 'D'
D.valid_max = np.int32(np.round(np.nanmax(d)))
D.valid_min = np.int32(np.round(np.nanmin(d)))
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Save data into NetCDF
TIME[:] = t
D[:] = np.ndarray.tolist(d)
VAR[:] =np.transpose(data_2_save)
dataset.close()# and the file is written
```

I then load the file later and plot as follows:

```
import xarray as xr
data = xr.open_dataset('test.nc')
data.VARIABLE[:,1].plot()
```

Then either the kernel crashes or a plot is produced. A different plot is produced everytime, with random numbers plotted alongside what I would expect (0., nan). These random numbers can be = ~20000, > e+38, and sometimes = 0. These random numbers tend to be at the end of the variable array where there are supposed to be NaNs. Sometimes there are no random numbers introduced.

**I have tried the following:**

- 'conda update --all'
- experiment with using 'np.int32', 'np.float64', 'float' when creating the variable in the NetCDF4 file
- changing the format from 'NETCDF-CLASSIC' to 'NETCDF4' when creating the NetCDF4 file

**Versions**

- Python 3.9
- xarray                    0.20.1
- matplotlib                3.5.1
- netcdf4                   1.5.7
- numpy                     1.21.5

I have recently reinstalled Anaconda and packages because of an issue using pip and conda to install packages.

I have tried this using Spyder and Jupyter Notebook, and it happens when using both.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem with jupyter notebook python=3.9 and Ubuntu. You might want to try switching to using the conda-forge channel. The latest version of xarray is 2022.6.0 there, so it's possible you are using a version with some compatibility issues

Comment: OK I'll give it a try, thanks. Although, this problem also occurs on a colleagues computer with a different environment suggesting that it might not be due to the version of xarray. I'm not sure. It's also possible that my simplified data example does not recreate the problem because it's a smaller sized matrix? perhaps trying a larger matrix might produce the problem? (e.g. 2,30000)

Comment: Does your example reproduce the problem on your machine?

Comment: I have updated the example above. It is very similar to the code used in my script, however it doesn't reproduce the same error. I am not sure why. The only thing that is different is the location of the NaNs and '0.'s in VARIABLE.

Comment: Note that the largest possible float is roughly `1e+38`.  It's like you are getting infinities.

Comment: Yeah that could be the case, but where are the infinities coming from? I've also tried switching 'data2save' with the real data set I want to save in my script and I got the same error. Hence it doesn't matter where the NaNs or '0.'s are. We can therefore rule out the data, and it must be the way I save or load the NetCDF file / variable.

Comment: I’d be slow to assume there’s something wrong with either package. These are very widely used and well tested packages, and you’re working with core functionality not some newfangled feature. So I think you’re right its more likely to be something about the data you’re writing or the way you’re reading it.

Comment: This is a pretty complicated example. It would be helpful (and would probably help identify the issue) if you could boil this down to a truly minimal [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make the NetCDF file using xarray instead of the netCDF4 package. The problem does not occur anymore.